# How to check if the electron app is running as Windows App or standalone exe?

Tags: windows, electron

I am developing an electron app. It will be packaged as a standalone exe as well as a windows store app.

If the election app is running as a standalone executable, I will check for updates.
If the electron app is running as windows store app, I needn't check for updates, as it will be handled by windows store.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to find out from within the electron app if it is running as a windows exe or windows app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Windows software development, but the property [process.windowsStore](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/process#processwindowsstore) could be what you're looking for, hopefully...

> `process.windowsStore`
>
> A `Boolean`. If the app is running as a Windows
>   Store app (appx), this property is `true`, for otherwise it is
>   `undefined`.